# Openatrium 1.0: How to get cases in the calendar

Tags: php, drupal, open-atrium

I was using Openatrium beta 10, and I used [this](http://drupal.org/project/casetracker_duedate) module to add due date to case tracker and show the cases in the calendar.  It works well.

When I upgraded OA to version 1.0, upgrade went ok except for a key feature.  The new release has added case due date, but there is no integration with the calendar.  We mainly use OA for managing tasks so this is a key feature.

I enabled the Case node type in the calendar view as recommended [here](https://community.openatrium.com/documentation-en/node/2407#can-i-add-a-due-date-to-t).  But that did not work because, the view logic is looking for field_date_value and field_date_value2 in the content_field_date table, which the case nodes don't have.

Not sure what to do this at this point.  I don't want to get stuck in the beta version, yet need this feature to upgrade.  Otherwise, OA is great for our need to manage several small teams with multiple projects.